# PHP. Как отправить данные на два E-mail'а?

Tags: php

Есть PHP, который отправляет данные на E-mail info@gmail.com. Как сделать, чтобы данные отправлялись кроме этого E-mail'а ещё и на второй?

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);
DEFINE('EMAIL_TO', 'info@gmail.com');

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: noreply@'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'' . "\r\n" .
              'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$message = "Имя: ".$_POST['name']."<br />";
if (!empty($_POST['email'])) $message .=  "Email: ".$_POST['email']."<br />";
if (!empty($_POST['phone'])) $message .=  "Телефон: ".$_POST['phone']."<br />";
if (!empty($_POST['info']))  $message .=  "Доп. информация: ".$_POST['info']."<br />";

switch ($_POST['form']) {
    case 'tyres':   
        mail(EMAIL_TO, 'Заявка на подбор шин/дисков', $message, $headers);
        break;

    case 'callback':
        mail(EMAIL_TO, 'Заказ звонка', $message, $headers);
        break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто перечислите всех адресатов в строке, являющейся первым аргументом mail. Формат адресатов должен соответствовать RFC 2822: к примеру, `User <user@example.com>, Another User <anotheruser@example.com>` или `user@example.com, anotheruser@example.com`